# Transfer big file from java to php using NuSoap

Tags: java, php, web-services, nusoap

I hope you can help me. I have a Web Service in PHP 5.5 created with NuSoap v 1.123 that can accept files.

I'm consuming the Web Service with a Java client that sends files in a base64 String that is embedded into the SOAP request, this method is good for small files because when I use big files the server takes too long to encode the String received.

Is there another manner to catch big files using NuSoap in php?

This is part of my function in the Web Service that receives the file.

```php
$current = base64_decode($documentEncoded);                          
// Now decode the content which was sent by the client     
if(!$current)
    return "La cadena codificada contiene carácteres que no estan dentro del alfabeto base64";
file_put_contents($location, $current);
```

Comment: Are you sure the string is not truncated on the (PHP) receiving end?  Am I understanding correctly you say PHP takes too long to base64_decode?  That sounds dubious.  And just as an FYI as to what you can expect with this performance wise...base64 "The ratio of output bytes to input bytes is 4:3 (33% overhead)".  Would drop the soap and look at multi-part file transfer.

Comment: Yes php takes too long to base64_decode for that reason I would like to know a way to do this more efficiently, when I want to send files who have 30 MB or more  of size  the SOAP  request is very big and that is the main problem because the decoding process is hard for the server.

Comment: On a 4 year old windows machine I can load a 30MB text log file, `base64_encode` and then `base64_decode` that in less that 0.247 seconds.  The decode part is about 1 tenth of a second.  I don't think your issue is specifically the compute time on the decode.  Probably more in the transport or something else.

Comment: fwiw: http://codepad.viper-7.com/s2h6hT